# Cast to user-defined data type in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, casting, types, user-defined

I have created a data type called id which consists of two text values:

id(text, text)

I now need to cast values to this data type before they are inserted into my table. How would I go about doing this?

I created the type as follows:

```
CREATE TYPE ID AS(id text, source text);
```

Comment: how did you create the data type? kindly show in question

Answer (score 4):

Well, to create a cast you need a function that takes a value of one type as your input and outputs the type you wish to cast to (in this case "ID" - which I would name a little more verbose if I were you).  What type do you want to cast from?

Realize without messing with all that, you should be able to use your type according to [this page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/rowtypes.html).

Just..
SELECT ROW('foo','bar')::ID ;

Answer (score 3):

You have to tell PostgreSQL how to cast, [CREATE CAST](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/sql-createcast.html)

Comment: So I need to create a function to do the cast for me? How exactly would I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

if we are talking about "user defined types" which are realy compatible with each other, so you can cast the type to text first and then to your custom type `admin_action::text::"UserAction"`

in my case "admin_action" was of type "AdminAction" and couldn't be converted to "UserAction" directly, but I've done it through "text" step.